# Haskell: cache result of a function in pattern matching

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming, tree

I have the following algebraic data type:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Also, I have

```
data Step = StepL | StepR
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Now, I need a function `search` that takes

1. a root of the tree
2. a target value `t`
   ... and it must return a path of type `[Step]` leading to a node with value `t`. Also, if `t` is not present in the tree, `search` must return `Nothing`. Finally, the input is guaranteed to have the target value at most once.

My best effort, as of now, is:

```
searchHelper :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> [Step] -> Maybe [Step]
searchHelper _ Empty _ = Nothing
searchHelper targetValue (Node nodeValue leftChild rightChild) stepsSoFar = 
  if targetValue == nodeValue then Just stepsSoFar 
  else if searchHelper targetValue leftChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepL]) /= Nothing then searchHelper targetValue leftChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepL])
  else if searchHelper targetValue rightChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepR]) /= Nothing then searchHelper targetValue rightChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepR])
  else Nothing

search :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe [Step]
search targetValue root = searchHelper targetValue root []
```

As you can see, I call the `searchHelper` too often (`else if searchHelper targetValue leftChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepL]) /= Nothing then searchHelper targetValue leftChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepL])`). I need a machinery that would allow me to cache the results of `searchHelper` calls and use them
in `if ... then ... else`.

Q: How can I do it?

Comment: How can we see that you call `searchHelper` too often? How much is *too often?* Why is it important?

Comment: @MarkSeemann If `searchHelper` returns non-`Nothing`, I call it twice to see what exactly did it return.

Comment: This problem looks super artificial and unrealistic. Are you sure you need this and not a *search* tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the word *cache* confused me, but if I understand the question correctly, the real problem is the repeated use of the same expression. That could certainly become a readability and maintainability issue in a larger code base, so is worthwhile addressing.

From the context this looks like a 'toy problem'. There's nothing wrong with that - I play with plenty of those myself to learn new stuff. The reason I mention it, though, is that from this and other clues I gather that you're still a Haskell beginner. Again: nothing wrong with that, but it just means that I'm going to skip some of the slightly more advanced Haskell stuff.

Checking for `Nothing` or `Just` like in the OP is rarely idiomatic Haskell. Instead you'd use pattern-matching or (more commonly) some of the higher-level APIs for working with `Maybe` (such as `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad`, etc.).

That said, I gather that this isn't quite what you need right now. In order to cut down on the duplication of expressions, you can use `let..in` syntax in Haskell:

```
searchHelper :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> [Step] -> Maybe [Step]
searchHelper _ Empty _ = Nothing
searchHelper targetValue (Node nodeValue leftChild rightChild) stepsSoFar = 
  if targetValue == nodeValue then Just stepsSoFar
  else
    let l = searchHelper targetValue leftChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepL])
    in if l /= Nothing then l
  else
    let r = searchHelper targetValue rightChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepR])
    in if r /= Nothing then r
  else Nothing
```

This enables you to 'declare' 'variables' `l` and `r` and reuse them.

As my lengthy preamble suggests, this still isn't idiomatic Haskell, but I hope it adresses the immediate question.

Comment: FWIW, Applicative and Monad aren't really called for here, so much as Alternative.. `(<|>)` solves exactly this problem.

Comment: Yes, correct, I am a Haskell beginner and the above snippet is one of the course exercises. Your solution is just what I needed, +1!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose a dissenting answer. The answer to the *general* question is indeed to use `let` (or `where`) to name the computation, and refer to that name twice. But the answer to this specific question is to dissolve the problem. Instead of:

```
if {- X -} /= Nothing then {- X -} else {- Y -}
```

use a `case` to inspect `X` and dispatch on its value. Like this:

```
case {- X -} of
    Nothing -> {- Y -}
    Just v -> Just v
```

This `Just v -> Just v` is very readable, but it does have an unfortunate operational interpretation: destructure the `Maybe` value, then immediately build a new `Maybe` value that's exactly the same. Rather than allocating a fresh value, you can simply return the one you've got using as-patterns: the pattern `var@pat` (where `var` is a variable name and `pat` is a pattern) matches exactly when `pat` matches, but also binds the name `var` to the entire value that was matched. So:

```
case {- X -} of
    Nothing -> {- Y -}
    v@(Just _) -> v
```

If we were to apply this pattern of rewrite to your original code, here's where we'd land:

```
searchHelper targetValue (Node nodeValue leftChild rightChild) stepsSoFar = 
  if targetValue == nodeValue then Just stepsSoFar 
  else case searchHelper targetValue leftChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepL]) of
         Nothing -> case searchHelper targetValue rightChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepR]) of
           Nothing -> Nothing
           v@(Just _) -> v
         v@(Just _) -> v
```

This rewrite reveals something quite nice: the inside `case` always returns the exact thing it sees! So we can simply return the exact thing it sees directly, without ever inspecting it with `case`.

```
searchHelper targetValue (Node nodeValue leftChild rightChild) stepsSoFar = 
  if targetValue == nodeValue then Just stepsSoFar 
  else case searchHelper targetValue leftChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepL]) of
         Nothing -> searchHelper targetValue rightChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepR])
         v@(Just _) -> v
```

This would be a fine spot for a beginner to stop. For an expert, I would expect at this point to notice that the `case` used above is an instance of the `(<|>)` function, defined so for `Maybe` values:

```
Nothing <|> r = r
l       <|> _ = l
```

So:

```
searchHelper targetValue (Node nodeValue leftChild rightChild) stepsSoFar = 
  if targetValue == nodeValue then Just stepsSoFar 
  else searchHelper targetValue leftChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepL])
   <|> searchHelper targetValue rightChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepR])
```

In this particular case, I think I would also consider converting the first part of the `if` to a bare `Maybe` value so that I could chain `<|>`s. That would give you one  of these (`asum` is the listified form of chaining `<|>`s):

```
-- the empty is just to make the following lines more uniform, it should be compiled away
searchHelper targetValue (Node nodeValue leftChild rightChild) stepsSoFar = empty
  <|> (stepsSoFar <$ guard (targetValue == nodeValue))
  <|> searchHelper targetValue leftChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepL])
  <|> searchHelper targetValue rightChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepR])

-- OR:
searchHelper targetValue (Node nodeValue leftChild rightChild) stepsSoFar = asum
  [ stepsSoFar <$ guard (targetValue == nodeValue)
  , searchHelper targetValue leftChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepL])
  , searchHelper targetValue rightChild (stepsSoFar ++ [StepR])
  ]
```

This fully addresses your original concern. To be really thorough with my suggestions, I'd also want to see `stepsSoFar` get built up in reverse; repeatedly prepending to a list is much cheaper than repeatedly appending.

```
searchHelper targetValue (Node nodeValue leftChild rightChild) stepsSoFar = asum
  [ reverse stepsSoFar <$ guard (targetValue == nodeValue)
  , searchHelper targetValue leftChild (StepL : stepsSoFar)
  , searchHelper targetValue rightChild (StepR : stepsSoFar)
  ]
```

At this point, I would consider this quite idiomatic Haskell. Whether the repetition in the final two elements of the `asum` bothers you is an aesthetic choice that I could see two experts disagreeing on. If it bothers you, it could be addressed like this:

```
searchHelper targetValue (Node nodeValue leftChild rightChild) stepsSoFar =
  (reverse stepsSoFar <$ guard (targetValue == nodeValue))
  <|>
    [ searchHelper targetValue child (step : stepsSoFar)
    | (child, step) <- [(leftChild, StepL), (rightChild, StepR)]
    ]
```

Personally I find the additional complexity not worth the sharing, so I would skip this change. (Actually, to be completely fair, I would probably make this change, look at it, and then revert it. ^_^)